# How to add a "Type" column to the file dialog?

Tags: gtk3, dialog, file-sorting

I haven't used Ubuntu for several years, and now that I'm giving it another try, the oversimplification and removal of features are kind of baffling.

[image: Wat]

The screenshot says it all. How can I add a "Type" column to the file dialog (e.g. to sort the files by type)?

Comment: This is browse / upload from a website or similar?

Comment: You have tagged the question `filemanager` - but your screenshot seems to be showing a *file selection dialog* from a specific application (Qt Creator maybe?). Can you clarify which you are referring to please?

Comment: @steeldriver QtCreator uses file selection dialogs provided by the operating system. I get exactly the same result with pretty much every other application which uses file selection dialogs (Firefox, etc...). AFAIK file selection dialog is provided by, and depends on, the default file manager (Nautilus in this case). Hence the tag. Also, I couldn't find "file-selection-dialog' tag and I don't have enough karma to add one myself.

Comment: @ScumCoder I think it's the other way around: the file chooser for an application is provided by the *toolkit* on which it's based. In the case of Gnome applications (including Nautilus), that's mostly Gtk. For example, one can toggle the 'Size' column in gedit's file selection using the `show-size-column` property of the `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser` schema (there isn't a `show-type-column` though).

Answer (score 1):

Umm it seems you can't:

[image]

I'm still searching for another solution...

gsettings has a nautilus config line (among others):

```
org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view captions
```

and has the value

```
['none', 'size', 'date_modified']
```

I tried changing this to include `type`:

```
['none', 'size', 'date_modified', 'type']
```

but it still didn't work. I'm not sure how it can be enabled.

Comment: I don't think it can do it, as I don't think the feature exists for file selection dialog boxes

Comment: @ThomasW. seems that way unfortunataly

Comment: indeed.  It can also be misleading too.